# How to ingest browser OpenTelemetry traces in Cloud Trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, open-telemetry

I am using instructions from https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs-ot to collect Node.js OpenTelemetrics to [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace). Now I want to add frontend stack traces.

I've tried adding `@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http`:

```
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { FetchInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fetch';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import {
  ConsoleSpanExporter,
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
  WebTracerProvider,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';

const consoleExporter = new ConsoleSpanExporter();

const collectorExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
  headers: {},
});

const provider = new WebTracerProvider({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'contra-web-app',
  }),
});

const fetchInstrumentation = new FetchInstrumentation({});

fetchInstrumentation.setTracerProvider(provider);

provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(consoleExporter));

provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(collectorExporter));

provider.register();

registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [fetchInstrumentation],

  tracerProvider: provider,
});

export const TraceProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

and I see it tries to send data to `/v1/traces`. However, nothing is listening on that endpoint.

What do I need to deploy to `/v1/traces` to have the traces ingested by Cloud Trace?

Comment: Relevant discussion https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-js/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, This is an experimental package under active development.[1]  Best approach for this is to submit a feature request to have this reviewed by product engineers if you need this for your use case.

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http

Comment: This is the inverse of what I am looking. I already have OTLP trace exporter. I am trying to wrap my head around how ingest these traces, i.e. which is the service that would ingest these requests and forward them to Google Cloud Trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy [opentelemetry-collector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector).

The way that I ended up doing it is using a [Helm chart](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts).

You then need to configure an otlp receiver, e.g.

```
otlp:
  protocols:
    http:
      include_metadata: true
      cors:
        allowed_origins:
          - https://gajus.com
      endpoint: ${env:MY_POD_IP}:4318
```

and expose it to the web using Ingress.

You then need to configure [`googlecloudexporter`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/exporter/googlecloudexporter/README.md) (it is already bundled in the Helm chart so you just need to configure it).

```
exporters:
  googlecloud:
    retry_on_failure:
      enabled: false
    log:
      default_log_name: opentelemetry.io/collector-exported-log
```

You then need to provide [`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#GAC) to this service with Cloud Trace API access scope, which you then mount like so:

```
  extraVolumes:
    - name: secret-mount
      secret: 
        secretName: contra-opentelemetry-collector-google-cloud
        optional: false
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: secret-mount
      mountPath: /var/secrets/google
  extraEnvs:
    - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
```

The whole thing might look something like this:

```
app:
  deployment:
    version: '0.0.0'
opentelemetry-collector:
  mode: deployment
  extraVolumes:
    - name: secret-mount
      secret: 
        secretName: contra-opentelemetry-collector-google-cloud
        optional: false
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: secret-mount
      mountPath: /var/secrets/google
  extraEnvs:
    - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
  ports:
    otlp:
      enabled: true
      containerPort: 4317
      servicePort: 4317
      hostPort: 4317
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: grpc
    otlp-http:
      enabled: true
      containerPort: 4318
      servicePort: 4318
      hostPort: 4318
      protocol: TCP
    jaeger-compact:
      enabled: false
    jaeger-thrift:
      enabled: false
    jaeger-grpc:
      enabled: false
    zipkin:
      enabled: false
    metrics:
      enabled: false
  config:
    receivers:
      jaeger: null
      prometheus: null
      zipkin: null
      otlp:
        protocols:
          http:
            include_metadata: true
            cors:
              allowed_origins:
                - https://gajus.com
            endpoint: ${env:MY_POD_IP}:4318
    exporters:
      googlecloud:
        retry_on_failure:
          enabled: false
        log:
          default_log_name: opentelemetry.io/collector-exported-log
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers:
            - otlp
          exporters:
            - googlecloud
        metrics: null
        logs: null
```